# ELF file structure in FreeBSD & Linux

Tags: c++, linux, freebsd, elf

In PE (for windows) it is possible to read the headers/sections of that structure by `#include<windows.h>` and can use the struct `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` to read the dos header in any PE file, for example.

How can i do that for ELF header in FreeBSD/Linux? What kind of preprocessor need to be added at the head of the C/C++ code?
and Is there any difference between FreeBSD and Linux in term of the structure of ELF?

Comment: The ELF structure will be available to you using a simple Google search.  I'm sure you can as easily find info on how to read it's headers.  Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, i tried to search but i can not see the answer easly due to the bad english i have.

Comment: Yeah, but asking for a lib to read ELF files in Linux is no worse than many other, answered questions on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/).

Comment: Or you can just use elf.h if you want which defines the relevant data structures.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the sources of readelf. Or just google. For example, this http://www.scribd.com/doc/7027807/ELF-Format looks promising.

If you just want existing code, try http://www.linux.com/learn/docs/man/2838-elf5.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some pointers which should help you out:

- Oracle article [LibElf and GElf - A Library to Manipulate ELf Files](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/elf.html)
- [GElf](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/3elf/gelf/)
- [Libelf homepage](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html)

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for FreeBSD, but on Linux there are a lot of details in the `elf(5)` manpage:

```
NAME
   elf - format of Executable and Linking Format (ELF) files

SYNOPSIS
   #include <elf.h>

DESCRIPTION
   The header file <elf.h> defines the format of ELF executable
   binary files.  Amongst these files are normal executable
   files, relocatable object files, core files and shared
   libraries.
...
```

When I needed to understand ELF, I found nothing more useful than the [MuppetLabs Tiny Executable](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) walk-through. I'm sure many of the techniques are out-of-date (and were never a good idea), but they explained things very well.